# How can I obtain the first row from a SELECT operation using JPQL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I have a database with data about some tests, I want to order them decently using their attribute DATE and take only the first one of all of them. I mean, the equivalent TOP 1 of SQL in JPQL.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11):

In spring jpa you can do something like this

```java
Foo findTopByOrderByDateDesc(); //This will return 1st item

List<Foo> findTop10ByOrderByDateDesc(); //This will return top 10 item
```

For reference [Spring Jpa Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)

Answer (score 5):

Mostly common

```
Foo findFirstByOrderByDateDESC();
```

Using **@Query** with `nativeQuery = true`

```
@Query(value="SELECT 1 * FROM "TableName" ORDER BY "DATE in db" DESC LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true)
Foo findFirstByOrderByDateDESC(Long id); // name can be random
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 5):

The question specifically asks how to do it in JPQL. The answer is that you can't. You either need to use a JPA query derived from a method name (as in jumping_monkey's answer) or use a native query.

Answer (score 4):

You normally set that on the `Query` object before triggering the fetch:

```
entityManager.createQuery("...")
       .setMaxResults(1)
       .getResultList();
```

With the use of Spring Data Jpa syntax you would use something like:

```
Optional<Test> findFirstByOrderByDateDesc();
```

Or using `Pageable`:

```
Page<Test> test = repository.findAll(
    PageRequest.of(0, 1, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "date")));
```

Comment: I am using the @Query annotation in the method defined in my repository as I am not too much familiarized with the JPA syntax and Pageable. So, I have something like "SELECT * FROM TEST t ORDER BY t.date DESC", and it returns all tests, but I want to add to the query like the TOP 1 of SQL, is there any option to take the first one in my way?

Comment: It seems you need option 2 here

Answer (score 3):

In [Spring Data JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-limit-query-results), use the keywords **first** or **top**, both are semantically the same, i prefer **top**, because there are 2 less letters to type ;-).

> Foo find**Top**ByOrderByDateDesc(); //Top 1 assumed
> Foo find**First**ByOrderByDateDesc(); //First 1 assumed

If you want to find the first X rows, where X is a number, use:

> List<Foo> find**TopX**ByOrderByDateDesc();
> List<Foo> find**FirstX**ByOrderByDateDesc();

If you want to remember to deal with null returns, wrap the result in an `Optional`:

> **Optional**<Foo> findTopByOrderByDateDesc();
> **Optional**<Foo> findFirstByOrderByDateDesc();